# How to create a veracrypt volume on the command line not interactively with a keyfile stored on a PKCS#11 token

Tags: linux, command-line, veracrypt, smartcard, pkcs

I am trying to create a new veracrypt container on the command line in a completely interactive fashion. To make things more complicated, I need to store a keyfile on a PKCS#11 token.

From what I understood, I first need to import the keyfile to the token before creating the volume. I have tried the commands

```
veracrypt --text --import-token-keyfiles --token-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so  --new-keyfiles=/tmp/keyfile.dat
```

and

```
veracrypt --text --import-token-keyfiles --token-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so  --keyfiles=/tmp/keyfile.dat
```

But both commands interactively ask for the keyfile

```
Enter keyfile [none]:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at [the source code](https://github.com/veracrypt/VeraCrypt/blob/2ab57bcf7074449a1088dbffac4e221eadc24631/src/Main/TextUserInterface.cpp#L1059) of Veracrypt, it appears that what I'm trying to achieve is unfortunately not possible.

```
void TextUserInterface::ImportSecurityTokenKeyfiles () const
    {
[...]
        shared_ptr <KeyfileList> keyfiles = AskKeyfiles();
[...]
```

The relevant function just asks for the keyfile interactively withous heeding command line switches.

As a ugly workaround, I found that this command works:

```
echo "/tmp/keyfile.dat\n"|veracrypt --text --import-token-keyfiles --token-lib=/usr/lib/mypkcs11lib.so --token-pin=123456
```